# Remove last string in logstash list

Tags: ruby, logstash

Here is my logstash configuration file :

```
 input {
    file {
            path           => "/usr/share/logstash/logs"
            codec           => "cef"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

 filter {
    mutate {
            split => { "deviceCustomString3" => "\r\n" }
    }
 }


output {
    stdout{}
 }
```

And an log extract :

```
{
     "deviceCustomString4Label" => "attack_type",
     "deviceCustomString2Label" => "http_class_name",
          "deviceCustomString4" => "Buffer Overflow",
                   "sourcePort" => "39651",
                   "requestUrl" => "/api/v1/auth/login",
                "sourceAddress" => "x.x.x.x",
          "deviceCustomString2" => "/Common/xxxxx",
                         "name" => "Illegal URL length",
            "devicePostReferer" => "Referer: https://xxxxx",
                     "@version" => "1",
                         "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/logs",
          "devicePostUserAgent" => "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "deviceCustomNumber1" => "201",
     "deviceCustomString5Label" => "x_forwarded_for_header_value",
                "deviceVersion" => "x.x.x",
                "deviceProduct" => "xxx",
                   "cefVersion" => "xxx:xxx:0",
                "deviceAddress" => "x.x.x.x",
          "deviceCustomString1" => "/Common/TEMPLATE",
          "deviceCustomString6" => "FR",
     "deviceCustomIPv6Address2" => "",
"deviceCustomIPv6Address4Label" => "ip_address_intelligence",
            "deviceReceiptTime" => "Nov 07 2018 03:51:11",
               "sourceUserName" => "N/A",
          "deviceCustomNumber2" => "3",
           "destinationAddress" => "x.x.x.x",
     "deviceCustomString6Label" => "geo_location",
            "deviceCustomDate1" => "Nov 06 2018 16:58:52",
"deviceCustomIPv6Address3Label" => "destination_address",
     "deviceCustomIPv6Address4" => "N/A",
     "deviceCustomNumber2Label" => "violation_rating",
           "deviceEventClassId" => "Illegal URL length",
                 "sourceUserId" => "7f4f66179a45f7ca",
                         "host" => "xxxxx",
                "requestMethod" => "POST",
                   "@timestamp" => 2018-11-07T15:23:12.590Z,
          "deviceCustomNumber3" => "0",
               "devicePostHost" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:62.0) Gecko/62.0 Firefox/62.0",
     "deviceCustomNumber1Label" => "response_code",
                 "deviceAction" => "alerted",
             "deviceExternalId" => "2",
     "deviceCustomIPv6Address1" => "",
     "deviceCustomString1Label" => "policy_name",
       "deviceCustomDate1Label" => "policy_apply_date",
                      "message" => "N/A",
                         "type" => "xxx",
     "deviceCustomString3Label" => "full_request",
"deviceCustomIPv6Address1Label" => "device_address",
                     "severity" => "4",
          "applicationProtocol" => "HTTPS",
          "deviceCustomString3" => [
    [ 0] "POST /api/v1/auth/login HTTP/1.1",
    [ 1] "Host: xxxx",
    [ 2] "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:62.0) Gecko/62.0 Firefox/62.0",
    [ 3] "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*",
    [ 4] "Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    [ 5] "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    [ 6] "Content-Type: text/plain",
    [ 7] "Referer: xxxxx",
    [ 8] "Content-Length: 61",
    [ 9] "Cookie: xxxxxxxxx,
    [10] "DNT: 1",
    [11] "Connection: keep-alive",
    [12] "X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x",
    [13] "",
    [14] "{\"login\":\"xxxx \",\"password\":\"xxxx\"}"
],
```

For the field `deviceCustomString3` there are many fields (0 to 14), but the length can change. I would like to add a filter to delete just the last field (the login and password one).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need a ruby snippet, read the payload in as an array and then delete the last item in the array. Even if the data was clean JSON you'd need some sort of logic in there so you could determine which line was last.

Alternatively you could do something with gsub & regex depending on how unique the last line of your data is (i.e. look for the data after "login": and "password":

The kv filter may help.

I am assuming you do not actually have end lines in there & the format above is from rubydebug?

Answer (score 0):

If your log is a hash you could simply do `log["deviceCustomString3"] = log["deviceCustomString3"][0..-2]` to delete the last element of the array.

Se the example below, I cut off the hash to keep it short.

```
log = {
        "deviceCustomString3" => 
          [
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x",
            "",
            "{\"login\":\"xxxx \",\"password\":\"xxxx\"}"
          ]
}

log["deviceCustomString3"] = log["deviceCustomString3"][0..-2]

log #=> {"deviceCustomString3"=>["Connection: keep-alive", "X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x", ""]}
```